# Same Query with different where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table as:

```
date        passed    failed   subject
2015-2-1      2          1        maths
2015-2-1      3          2        cs
2015-3-1      1          2        maths
2015-12-1     2          1        maths
```

I have a form to select the start date and end date.
for eg:If I select `startdate = 2015-2-1` and `enddate=2015-3-1` 
my output should be:

```
date        passed   failed   
2015-2-1     5         3
2015-3-1     1          2
```

output should contain the total no of passed and failed (irrespective of subjects) for same months as shown above.

This is the query which I used:
`startdate=2015-2-1` and `enddate=2015-3-1`

```
SELECT SUM(passed) ,SUM(failed) FROM student_log WHERE
(DATE(`date`)='2015-2-1')
union
SELECT SUM(passed) ,SUM(failed) FROM student_log WHERE
(DATE(`date`)='2015-3-1')
```

It works fine But if my end date is December I should repeat my union query till December...
Please suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
SELECT SUM(passed), SUM(failed), DATE(`date`) 
FROM student_log 
WHERE DATE(`date`) >= '2015-2-1' AND DATE(`date`) <= '2015-3-1'
GROUP BY DATE(`date`);
```

This would find all tests between two dates and give you a count from each day.

Comment: Thank u its perfect :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You dont need separate **queries** or **join** or **union** for this

```
SELECT SUM(`pass`) as total_pass, SUM(`fail`) as total_fail 
FROM pass_fail 
WHERE (`date` = '2015-2-1' or `date` = '2015-3-1' ) 
GROUP BY `date`
```

> Output

[image]

> Refer [Group By](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html)

Answer (score 1):

this query :

```
Select date,sum (passed),sum(failed) from Results group by date
```

returns the following results for me :

```
date   passed   failed


2015-02-01  5       3

2015-03-01  1       2

2015-12-01  2       1
```

In other words: The group by clause will display the data per Month as you need it.